# Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : Specified driver could not be loaded (msodbcsql11.dll)

Tags: sql-server-2014, sqlcmd, system-error

when I try to run the **sqlcmd** command in the command line, I get the following error message:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 193:  (ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server, C:\Windows\system32\msodbcsql11.dll)

I checked **"C:\Windows\system32\"** directory and I can see that the the dll is located correctly:

[DLL is located in the directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDLOY.png)

I also double checked that "Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server" is installed (version 12.0.2000.8).

**OS:** Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

**SQL Server Version:** Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64) 
    Feb 20 2014 20:04:26 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: )

Any ideas why I cannot run the command **sqlcmd** in the command line?

Thanks a lot in advance, 
Roman

Comment: Error 193 is `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT`. You typically get this when a 32-bit process attempts to load a 64-bit DLL or vice versa. Is the `sqlcmd` process you invoke 32-bit, by any chance? Try checking your PATH to see if there's anything funny in there.

Comment: Of course, `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT` could also simply mean that, well, the DLL is corrupt. Try verifying it against a checksum list (or simply reinstall).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded Dependency Walker and realized that **msodbcsql11.dll** is really x86 instead of x64. I replaced the DLL and everything works fine.

Thanks for your help, Roman